_reboot.scss overwrites in ASP.NET Core MVC
Whenever I put a <p> tag in the HTML it has a margin which is I think it is the default margin of it. I am expecting that the tag has a zero padding and margin because the bootstrap implemented it that way.
I inspected the elements in my browser and found out that _reboot.scss is the culprit:

I have tried to put the following code in the site.css but still the <p> tag has a margin:
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

I did not change anything inside the head tag, I have tried to comment out the <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/TestProject.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />. But nothing is working.
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TestProject</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/TestProject.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>

Is there any way I can prevent the _reboot.scss to not overwrite my css?
By the way, this is my first time using ASP.NET Core MVC.

You're still importing Bootstrap...

@Dai, yes. Correct.

when importing bootstrap _reboor.scss is also imported and when you try to * {    margin: 0;    padding: 0; } beacause this is an global css selecter it has les priotity over the element so if you had as an selector p it should work or use !important but the actual better way to do it is to style everything after the bootstrap style link and style the page how you would like it
